# Inventar Procedimento de Confirmação de cadastro

Tags: asp.net-mvc, envio-de-email

A ideia é após realizar o cadastro, enviar ao usuário um e-mail contendo um link, onde ele possa confirmar de fato o cadastro e só assim liberar a permissão para logar. Só para ter um pouco mais de segurança e impedir que qualquer e-mail seja cadastrado. Como fazer?

Comment: Você já está aqui há um bom tempo, por favor, dê uma olha nesses links http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas?lq=1, http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297/quando-se-deve-colocar-o-nome-da-linguagem-no-t%c3%adtulo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Só para ter um pouco mais de segurança e impedir que qualquer e-mail seja cadastrado. Como fazer?

Usando um atributo chamado [`[EmailAddress]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.emailaddressattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) no seu campo de e-mail. Ele valida perfeitamente se a `string` é um e-mail válido ou não.

```
[EmailAddress]
public String MeuEnderecoDeEmail { get; set; }
```

### A ideia é após realizar o cadastro, enviar ao usuário um e-mail contendo um link, onde ele possa confirmar de fato o cadastro e só assim liberar a permissão para logar.

Para isso, você precisa criar um padrão para a confirmação. Por exemplo, uma token em `base64`. Segue dois métodos para gerar uma token:

```
public static string Base64Encode(string minhaString) {
    var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(minhaString);
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
}

public static string Base64Decode(string stringCriptografada) {
    var bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(stringCriptografada);
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
}
```

Faça um método que gere uma token como essa (a string de entrada você define) e salve ela no seu *Model*.

Para montar um e-mail, você pode usar um serviço como o [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) que já tem uma boa solução pronta para ser usada. [Aqui eles ensinam como montar e enviar um e-mail pela sua aplicação](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp#how-to-create-an-email).

Comment: Entendi. Mas a minha duvida continua sendo em como mandar esse e-mail. Tenho visto alguns códigos utilizando controllers assíncronos. Você teria algum exemplo ou tutorial mais concreto?

Comment: @RyanSantos Atualizei minha resposta.